# Decrease power of a signal by a specific dB in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have a vector of data of a signal that was collected and want to decrease its power by 10dB. How would I go about doing that? Is there a universal way to decrease the power of a signal, or is dependent on the type of signal?

Edit: My signal is in IQ Baseband

Comment: please provide an example, so you get the answer you expect, otherwise your question is not clear and can be interpreted in different ways

Comment: Decreasing the power by `d` dB is the same as multiplying the signal by the scalar `10^(-d/20)`. There's not much more to it

Answer (score 0):

let say you have the following vector whose values are power in dBm:

```
x = [10, 20, 28, 28, 10];
```

If you want to decrease their power by 10 dB, you just need to subtract all the values by 10

```
y = x - 10;
```

If your original values are in linear scale (mW) such as

```
x = [10 32  787  212   10]
```

You need to first convert them to dBm and then subtract 10 dB

```
y = pow2db(x) - 10;
```

if your original vector are in I/Q complex value such as :

```
x = complex(randn(1,20), randn(1,20));
```

You can do this for decrease their power by 10 dB:

```
y = 1/db2mag(10)*x;
```